# Speed of PHP UDP scraper is incredibly slow, how to improve?

Tags: php, performance, sockets

I am working on a little project of mine and have built a UDP scraper that uses sockets to return data about a specific `sha1` hash.

It works but is incredibly slow and wondered if any one knows how I could speed it up or improve the existing code.

The code is below;

```
// SCRAPE UDP
private function scrapeUDP($tracker, $hash) {
    // GET TRACKER DETAILS
    preg_match('%udp://([^:/]*)(?::([0-9]*))?(?:/)?%i', $tracker, $info);
    // GENERATE TRANSACTION ID
    $transID = mt_rand(0, 65535);
    // PACKED TRANSACTION ID
    $packedTransID = pack('N', $transID);
    // ATTEMPT TO CREATE A SOCKET
    if(!$socket = @fsockopen('udp://' . $info[1], $info[2], $errno, $errstr, 2)) {
        return;
    }
    // SET STREAM TIMEOUT
    stream_set_timeout($socket, 2);
    // CONNECTION ID
    $connID = "\x00\x00\x04\x17\x27\x10\x19\x80";
    // BUILD CONNECTION REQUEST PACKET
    $packet = $connID . pack('N', 0) . $packedTransID;
    // SEND PACKET
    fwrite($socket, $packet);
    // CONNECTION RESPONSE
    $response = fread($socket, 16);
    // CHECK CONNECTION RESPONSE LENGTH
    if(strlen($response) < 16) {
        return;
    }
    // UNPACK CONNECTION RESPONSE
    $returnData = unpack('Naction/NtransID', $response);
    // CHECK CONNECTION RESPONSE DATA
    if($returnData['action'] != 0 || $returnData['transID'] != $transID) {
        return;
    }
    // GET CONNECTION ID
    $connID = substr($response, 8, 8);
    // BUILD SCRAPE PACKET
    $packet = $connID . pack('N', 2) . $packedTransID . $hash;
    // SEND SCRAPE PACKET
    fwrite($socket, $packet);
    // SCRAPE RESPONSE
    $response = fread($socket, 20);
    // CHECK SCRAPE RESPONSE LENGTH
    if(strlen($response) < 20) {
        return;
    }
    // UNPACK SCRAPE RESPONSE
    $returnData = unpack('Naction/NtransID', $response);
    // CHECK SCRAPE RESPONSE DATA
    if($returnData['action'] != 2 || $returnData['transID'] != $transID) {
        return;
    }
    // UNPACK SCRAPE INFORMATION
    $returnData = unpack('Nseeders/Ncompleted/Nleechers', substr($response, 8, 12));
    // RETURN TRACKER INFORMATION
    return array('seeders' => $returnData['seeders'], 'leechers' => $returnData['leechers'],);
}
```

It is my first time I have ever created anything to do with sockets or UDP so forgive me if it is a mess!

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make parallel request using [socket_select()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) and non-blocking sockets or [forks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php), because you are spending a lot of time in waiting for the response. Additionally, it may be better to use low-level functions like socket_read() or similar to control connection and data transmission better.